# filter searching in diferent divs

Tags: jquery, html, twig

im trying to filter the articles i have in my program to a search in jquery that is working, the problem is that i only want it to search in a determineted div but instead this is searching tro all my articles, like if i search in the div "processador", this is searching in "grafica" for example.

http://prntscr.com/iuqsxu

http://prntscr.com/iuqsnl

Jquery

```
var divs = $('.expandContent');
$('.expand').each(function () {
    $(this).find('.product-removal').slice(2).hide();
    $(".search").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      $('div.product-removal article.product').each(function() {
          $(this).toggle($(this).html().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
      });
    });
});
```

Processador code

```
<div id="processador" class="expandContent expand">
        <h3 class="header">
            <div class="headerColumn1">Processador</div>
            <div class="headerColumn2 expand"><img src="img/plus.png"/></div>
            <div class="expandedContentClearFloat"></div>
        </h3>
        <div class="expandedContent">
          <input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Search...">
            {% for item in processador %}

            <div class="product-removal"  >

                <article class="product">
                    <header>
                        <img src="{{ item.img|e }}">
                    </header>
                    <div class="content" >
                        <button name="proc" id="{{ item.id|e }}" type="button"
                                class="close close-processador pull-right" aria-label="Close"
                                data-id="{{ item.id|e }}" data-preco="{{ item.preco_unit|e }}">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                        <h1>{{ item.marca|e }}</h1>
                        {{ item.descr|e }}
                    </div>
                    <footer class="content">
                        <h2 class="full-price fixed fixed-processador">
                            {{ item.preco_unit|e }}€
                        </h2>
                        <a data-versao="{{item.versao|e}}" class="adicionar adicionar-processador pull-right full-price"
                           data-modelo="{{ item.modelo|e }}" data-id="{{ item.id|e }}"
                           data-preco="{{ item.preco_unit|e }}">
                            <h2 class="full-price">
                                {{ item.preco_unit|e }}€
                            </h2>
                        </a>
                        <h2 class="price">
                            {{ item.preco_unit|e }}
                        </h2>
                    </footer>
                </article>
            </div>

            {% endfor %}
            <button class="mostrar" data-estado="mostrar">mostrar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

/grafic card code

```
<div id="grafica" class="expandContent expand">
        <h3 class="header">
            <div class="headerColumn1">Graficas</div>
            <div class="headerColumn2 expand"><img src="img/plus.png"/></div>
            <div class="expandedContentClearFloat"></div>
        </h3>
        <div class="expandedContent">
          <input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Search...">
            {% for item in placagrafica %}
            <div class="product-removal">
                <article class="product">
                    <header>
                        <img src="{{ item.img|e }}" class="iconcomp">
                    </header>
                    <div class="content">
                        <button name="proc" id="{{ item.id|e }}" type="button"
                                class="close close-grafica pull-right" aria-label="Close"
                                data-id="{{ item.id|e }}" data-preco="{{ item.preco_unit|e }}" data-quantidade="">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                        <h1>{{ item.marca|e }}</h1>
                        {{ item.descr|e }}
                    </div>
                    <footer class="content">
                        <span class="qt-minus">-</span>
                        <span class="qt" id="quantgraf" data-id="{{ item.id|e }}">1</span>
                        <span class="qt-plus">+</span>
                        <h2 class="full-price fixed fixed-grafica">
                            {{ item.preco_unit|e }}€
                        </h2>
                        <a data-versao="{{item.versao|e}}" class="adicionar adicionar-grafica pull-right full-price"
                           data-modelo="{{ item.modelo|e }}" data-id="{{ item.id|e }}"
                           data-preco="{{ item.preco_unit|e }}" data-quantidade="">
                            <h2 class="full-price">
                                {{ item.preco_unit|e }}€
                            </h2>
                        </a>
                        <h2 class="price">
                            {{ item.preco_unit|e }}
                        </h2>
                    </footer>
                </article>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <button class="mostrar" data-estado="mostrar">mostrar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the code, you are trying to search from all the products.
$('div.product-removal article.product') will return all the .products from #processador and #grafica because all are having the same class names.

You should update your code to search only within that particular section.

```
$(".expand .search").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(this).parent().find('article.product').each(function() {
        if ($(this).html().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)) {
            $(this).show();
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
     });
});
```

I've also optimised your code a little.

$(this).parent().find('article.product') will only select the products within that section.

Answer (score 0):

> The class selector returns a group of elements.
>
> The id selector returns single element with first element with matching id.

Both the divs are having the same class and you are applying your `JQuery` functions on class. Instead you give unique ids for each div.

i.e., on search you are manipulating using `$('div.product-removal article.product')` which is applying for both the matched elements.

Comment: didnt understand